# Python and jupyter are not recognized even when in path

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook

The only way for me to start Jupyter is to navigate to the directory. However, when I open the notebook it's already filled with various system files which I don't want to override. Is there a way to simply run python and Jupiter notebook directly from my desktop dir? Here's my python and jupyter path:

```
C:\Python36\Scripts;

C:\Users\opodopri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe;

C:\Users\opodopri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

[image: Powershell]
[image: Powershell2]
[image: Jupyter]
[image: Jupyter notebook]

Comment: have you installed these programs on your computer?

Comment: You need to add C:\Users\opodopri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\ to your PATH variable.

Comment: @Abdou still getting the same error as in the screenshots

Comment: You need edit the PATH and then restart the command line application if you want the changes to take effect. If it's still not working, then you need to find the folder where these applications ***actually*** and add the path to that folder to your PATH variable.